# Given n, find smallest m such that n divides m and m contains only 4's followed by 0's

Tags: algorithm

I recently came upon this question during a test. Given a number n, find the smallest number m such that n divides m and m is a number consisting of only digit 4's followed by digit 0's. For example m can be 44400, 40000,444440 but not 404, 4404 etc.

My approach was to find all such numbers until INT_MAX, store them in a vector and then test for each case separately if n divides v[i] while iterating through the vector.

Obviously there is a better method to solve it as my approach was only partially accepted. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Edit: n can be as large as 1000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider all the numbers `4, 44, 444, 4444, ...` and so on and check whether they are divisible by `n`. If you consider `n+1` of them then you will find atleast `2` of them which are having same modulo remainder of `n`. You can subtract them (smallest of them) and then that is your answer.

Suppose `n` is `717`.

```
Then at first you consider 4 and  remainder is 4.
Now you consider 44 and remainder is same as (4*10+4).
Now you consider 444 and remainder is (44*10+4) or 444.
Now 4444 and remainder = ((444*10)%717+4)%717= 138+4= 142.
Now 44444 and remainder = ((142*10)%717+4)%717= 707.
```

Comment: Nice solution!! I did forget to mention that n could be as large as 1000. In that case we would need a data structure to do the arithmetic as long long int would not be sufficient in this approach. Nevertheless I think this is the solution they were looking for.

Comment: @user2980096.: Even in that case you can do that..you don't need to form the number to get that. You just do the mod arithmetic...(no data structure needed).

Comment: Can you please elaborate? For example in the sequence if i want to find the modulo of the nth term, i.e 4444....(n digits). Don't I need this number to find the modulo?

Comment: @user2980096.: I will elaborate in my answer